# Can anyone please help me identify this diode and possibly link me to a datasheet

Tags: diodes

I need to replace this part on another identical board. Any information on what type of diode this could be or maybe a datasheet link. I have searched the internet and I have come up empty handed.

[image: Image of Diode]

Comment: More than likely it's made by Fairchild (now owned by ON semiconductor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an ON Semiconductor [MRA4004T3G](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MRA4003T3-D.PDF)

[image]

Marking code R14 = MRA4004T3G

It is rated for 400V and 1A.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a MRA4004 from OnSemi. Rectifier 400V, 1A SMA DO214AC pkg.
Ooops ! Beaten to the punch!